# I accidentally turned on screen reader with my keyboard

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

I had my keyboard on my lap, and I adjusted my sitting position. I accidentally pressed some keys while doing this. I heard a robotic voice saying that the screen reader was turned on. After that, I got a barrage of narration each time I typed anything.

I was able to turn off screen reader in the Accessibility settings. However, I am unsure how it got turned on in the first place. The only window in the forefront of my screen was chromium.

Does anyone know what keyboard shortcut I may have pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation, it’s <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

[https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-screen-reader.html.en#:~:text=Press%20Super%20%2B%20Alt%20%2B%20S%20](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-screen-reader.html.en#:%7E:text=Press%20Super%20%2B%20Alt%20%2B%20S%20).